# HX711 Wemos D1 Weird Characters In Serial Monitor

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, arduino-ide, wifi

I am using the HX711 with a load cell attached on my Wemos D1. I have the connections correctly as if I use the same setup on my Arduino Uno board and the same code it runs fine and prints to the serial log. If I comment out the HX711 scale(DOUT, CLK); in my code the serial print is fine. I am not sure if this is an issue with the board or something I am doing with it. I would use the Arduino Uno but it does not have Wifi whereas my Wemos board does. Attached is a screenshot of the serial print from the monitor.

[image]

```
#include "HX711.h"

#define DOUT  3
#define CLK  2



HX711 scale(DOUT, CLK);

float calibration_factor = -117441.00; //-7050 worked for my 440lb max scale setup

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("HX711 calibration sketch");
  Serial.println("Remove all weight from scale");
  Serial.println("After readings begin, place known weight on scale");
  Serial.println("Press + or a to increase calibration factor");
  Serial.println("Press - or z to decrease calibration factor");
  scale.set_scale();
  scale.tare(); //Reset the scale to 0

  long zero_factor = scale.read_average(); //Get a baseline reading
  Serial.print("Zero factor: "); //This can be used to remove the need to tare the scale. Useful in permanent scale projects.
  Serial.println(zero_factor);
}

void loop() {

  scale.set_scale(calibration_factor); //Adjust to this calibration factor

  Serial.print("Reading: ");
  Serial.print(scale.get_units(), 1);
  Serial.print(" lbs"); //Change this to kg and re-adjust the calibration factor if you follow SI units like a sane person
  Serial.print(" calibration_factor: ");
  Serial.print(calibration_factor);
  Serial.println();

  if(Serial.available())
  {
    char temp = Serial.read();
    if(temp == '+' || temp == 'a')
      calibration_factor += 10;
    else if(temp == '-' || temp == 'z')
      calibration_factor -= 10;
  }
}
```

Comment: had you tried using other pins like 8,9 in place of 2,3

Comment: @Vaibhav Yup, tried that

Comment: io 3 is TX of Serial. use Dx constants to match the labels on board https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/402066/esp8266-free-gpios-for-relay-switching/404845#404845

Comment: @Juraj This does not make a lot of sense and does not solve my issue. My board does not look like that it looks like this https://storage.googleapis.com/stateless-www-faranux-com/2017/06/Reloaded-295x300.jpg and in this image my hx711 is hooked up to D3 and D3

Comment: ok, you have the D1 R1. on Wemos D1 R1 the pin labeled D3 is io 5 of the esp8266. in code use D3 not 3. https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/4e0e4e4340e6110cbb63ff77cb43d316cc318368/variants/d1/pins_arduino.h#L38

Comment: @Juraj I tried replacing 3 in the code with both D3 or even 0 as defined in that Github but both didn't work. I also tried replacing 2 with D2 or 4 as that code specifies but that also didn't work for me

Comment: @Juraj Okay cool now I am using D3 in the spot of 3 and D2 in the spot of 2 and it's working! Perfect.